# The WebDriver initialized in BaseClass is not getting inherited in PageClass

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, inheritance, testng

I am writing a simple Selenium with TestNG code. I have initialized the driver in the Base Class and both the page class and test class are extending base class, however, the driver is not getting inherited in the page class. However, the same driver is getting inherited in the test class. Can someone please explain why this is happening? **Edited: removed the WebDriver driver from the pageclass but it giving the same error :java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null**

**Base Class**

```
public class BaseClass {
protected WebDriver driver;
protected String username;
protected String password;
protected String browserName;
protected String url;

@BeforeSuite
public void setUp() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    username = "admin";
    password = "admin";
    browserName = "chrome";
    url = "https://practice-cybertekschool.herokuapp.com/";

    // get the driver setp and type and the browser
    if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("FireFox")) {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Edge")) {
        WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
    }

    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    driver.get(url);

}

@AfterSuite
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

**Page Class**

```
 public class BasicAuthPages extends BaseClass {

    By congratulationMessage = By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Congratulations')]");
    

// for authentication
public boolean authentication() {

    driver.get("https://"+username+":"+password+"@practice-cybertekschool.herokuapp.com/basic_auth");
    return authenticationMessage();
}

// to get authentication message
private boolean authenticationMessage() {
    String message = driver.findElement(congratulationMessage).getText();
    //System.out.println(message);
    if (message.equals("Congratulations! You must have the proper credentials.")) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

**Test Class**

```
public class Tests extends BaseClass {
    BasicAuthPages basicAuthPages;
    

@Test
public void authTest() {
    basicAuthPages = new BasicAuthPages();
    Boolean success = basicAuthPages.authentication();
    // System.out.println(username+" :"+password);
    Assert.assertTrue(success);
}
}
```

On running this, it gives java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null exception. However, the driver gets initialized in Test class and if I make the following changes, it runs.

**Base Class**

```
public class BaseClass {
protected WebDriver driver;
protected String username;
protected String password;
protected String browserName;
protected String url;

@BeforeSuite
public void setUp() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    username = "admin";
    password = "admin";
    browserName = "chrome";
    url = "https://practice-cybertekschool.herokuapp.com/";

    // get the driver setp and type and the browser
    if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("FireFox")) {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Edge")) {
        WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
    }

    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    driver.get(url);

}

@AfterSuite
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

**Page Class**

```
public class BasicAuthPages extends BaseClass {
WebDriver driver;
By congratulationMessage = By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Congratulations')]");

public BasicAuthPages(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

// for authentication
public boolean authentication(String username, String password) {
    driver.get("https://"+username+":"+password+"@practice-cybertekschool.herokuapp.com/basic_auth");
    return authenticationMessage();
}

// to get authentication message
private boolean authenticationMessage() {
    String message = driver.findElement(congratulationMessage).getText();
    //System.out.println(message);
    if (message.equals("Congratulations! You must have the proper credentials.")) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

**Test Class**

```
public class Tests extends BaseClass {
BasicAuthPages basicAuthPages;
CheckBoxPages checkBoxPages;

@Test
public void authTest() {
    basicAuthPages = new BasicAuthPages(driver);
    Boolean success = basicAuthPages.authentication(username, password);
    // System.out.println(username+" :"+password);
    Assert.assertTrue(success);
}
}
```

**Please someone explain me why the driver is not getting inherited in the first case? The driver gets inherited in the second one where it gets inherited in the test class and why not on the first one on the page class? Thank you in advance**

Comment: just because you've extended a class doesn't mean all new class objects inherit the same instance of that super object.  They'll inherit properties and methods that are defined there (unless overridden) but without dependency injection you won't have the same driver.  I'd stick with your frameworks architecture, which seems to be more about static classes.

Answer (score 1):

Make below change so that Driver it is stored as Static will tie it to Class rather Instance of the Class

```
protected WebDriver driver;
```

to

```
protected static WebDriver driver;
```

When you are Inheriting Base class everything will be null as your inheriting the properties of this class ,not the initialisation done in BaseClass by TestNG

Comment: thank you for the comment but can I ask why the driver is initialized in the test class and not thrown as null? Is it because of the TestNG annotations?

Comment: @Sandesh TestNg will call the setUp() Method in Your baseClass annotated with BeforeSuite Annotation and it will initialise the driver but you are not storing the created driver anywhere,Once TestNG is done with this method execution that driver instance is gone

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this  *java.lang.NullPointerException* because, in your first 'BasicAuthPages' class, you have declared `Webdriver driver`  but this driver is NOT initialized.

Whereas, in your second 'BasicAuthPages' class, 'driver' is initialized under the constructor of 'BasicAuthPages' class. Hence, its working fine.

In first case, since you're extending the base class, no need to declare `Webdriver driver`  again in your page class 'BasicAuthPages'. Since you have only declared the driver but not initialized, you're getting NullPOinterException when you're trying to access driver.

Comment: I removed the WebDriver driver declration from the page class but it is again showing the same error. java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want to run tests in parallel (needed for a big suite of tests to run as quickly as possible) then the driver is best initialised in the test class

If the Page Object classes inherit from the Base class, then pass in the driver during initalisation

Answer (score 0):

Try using `super()` keyword in the `BaseAuthPages` constructor as below:

```
public class BasicAuthPages extends BaseClass {

//WebDriver driver;
public BasicAuthPages() {
        super();
}   
By congratulationMessage = By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Congratulations')]");
```

`super` keyword is used to refer to parent class objects. In your case, to the `BaseClass` objects.

Comment: It did not work. I am getting the same Null Pointer Exception. java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.get(String)" because "this.driver" is null